# Why is this MATLAB script taking so long to execute?

Tags: matlab, performance, optimization

I'm trying to simulate the performance of an LDPC code on a BPSK AWGN channel when using sum-product decoding.

For this, I've written a function in MATLAB that follows the algorithm described [in the 34th page of this paper](http://sigpromu.org/sarah/SJohnsonLDPCintro.pdf). However, when I use the function I've written with parity-check matrices of large dimension (I need to use a matrix of 1012 x 1518), the program takes FOREVER to do a single iteration (I'm trying to simulate the performance of the code in this channel by doing at least 100k iterations to have a good estimation). The matrix H I'm using is of **very** low density (it only has two 1's per column), so I would expect the script to run way faster.

I thought that maybe using `float` to represent matrices with only 0's and 1's may be the issue, but I'm not sure if this would mean a huge change. Also, I wouldn't know how to perform some of the operations I use in my function if these matrices were boolean.

So does anyone have any idea? I'll put the function I wrote below.

```
function y = sum_product(r, H, I_max)

[m , n] = size(H);

I = 0;

for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:m
        if H(j,i) == 1
            M(j,i) = r(i);
        else
            M(j,i) = 0;
        end
    end
end

M = sparse(M);

E = M;

while 1

for j = 1:m
    for i = 1:n
        aux = 1;
        if H(j,i) == 1
            for l = 1:n
                if l~=i & H(j,l) == 1
                    aux = tanh(M(j,l)/2)*aux;
                end
            end
            E(j,i) = log(1+aux)-log(1-aux);
        end
    end
end

for i = 1:n
    aux = 0;
    for j = 1:m
        if H(j,i) == 1
            aux = aux + E(j,i);
        end
    end

    L(i) = aux + r(i);

    z(i) = L(i)<=0;
end

if I == I_max | mod((H*transpose(z)) , 2) == 0
    break;
else
    for i = 1:n
        for j = 1:m
            aux = 0;
            if H(j,i) == 1
                for l = 1:m
                    if l~=j & H(l,i) == 1
                        aux = aux + E(l,i);
                    end
                end
            M(j,i) = aux + r(i);
            end
        end
    end
I = I + 1;
end
end

y = z;

end
```

Comment: What version of MATLAB? What are the values of `r`, `H`, and `I_max` that reproduce the performance issue? Have you [profiled your code](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html) to identify where the majority of computation time is being spent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in other answer stated vectorization often will speed your computation. It means that instead of running the same function multiple times for each element of a matrix you can only run the function once for the whole matrix. If you are more comfortable with loops and `if else` statements you may consider using languages such as c++ to reach the desired speed.  So here is a vectorized form;

```
function z = sum_product(r, H, It_max)
    m  = size(H,1);
    n  = size(H,2);
    M = repmat(r,m,1);
    L = zeros(m,n);
    E = zeros(m,n);
    x = reshape(1:numel(H),m,n).';
    idx1= reshape(x(logical(H')),[],m).';
    idx2= reshape(find(H),[],n);
    for It = 0:It_max
        tn = tanh(M(idx1)/2);
        pr = bsxfun(@rdivide,prod(tn,2),tn);
        E(idx1) = log((1+ pr)./(1-pr));
        sumE = sum(E(idx2));
        L = sumE + r;
        z = L <= 0;
        if all(mod(H * z.',2) == 0)
            break;
        end
        M(idx2) = bsxfun(@plus,bsxfun(@minus,sumE , E(idx2) ),r);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you probbaly should not be using `for`-loops, nested loops even less so, as Matlab is an interpreted language. To speed things up try to vectorize your operations to make use of the speed of MATLAB's built in functions.

Comment: Interpreted vs. compiled is not relevant here. There are plenty of interpreted languages that have fast looping. The performance gap of loops vs. vectorized built-ins in MATLAB is also shrinking as the language matures so this is no longer a valid absolute blanket statement and certainly doesn't answer the question. The OP should [profile the code](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html) to identify where the computation time is being spent.